# bokeh sample data download fail with 'HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden'

Tags: bokeh

When trying to download bokeh sample data following instructions in 'https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/installation.html#sample-data' it fails to download with HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

in conda prompt:
bokeh sampledata    (failed)

in Jupyter notebook

> > > import bokeh.sampledata
> > >       bokeh.sampledata.download()   (failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; you will either need to upgrade to Bokeh version 1.3 or later, or else you can manually edit the `bokeh.util.sampledata` module to use the new CDN location `http://sampledata.bokeh.org`. You can see the exact change to make in [PR #9075](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/9075/files)

The `bokeh.sampledata` module originally pulled data directly from a public AWS S3 bucket location hardcoded in the module. This was a poor choice that left open the possibility for abuse, and in late 2019 an incident finally happened where someone (intentionally or unintentionally) downloaded the entire dataset tens of thousands of times over a three day period, incurring a significant monetary cost. (Fortunately, AWS saw fit to award us a credit to cover this anomaly.) Starting in version 1.3 sample data is now only accessed from a proper CDN with much better cost structures. All public direct access to the original S3 bucket was removed. This change had the unfortunate effect of immediately breaking `bokeh.sampledata` for all previous Bokeh versions, however as an open-source project we simply cannot afford the real (and potentially unlimited) financial risk exposure.